# Is there standard significance to A, B, and C/1, 2, 3 listed in job postings? (i.e., research coordinator A, research coordinator B etc.)

Tags: job-search, work-experience, job-description

I've noticed that a lot of positions list a number or letter after them. Is intended to indicate a specific level of expertise/years of experience? something else?

Comment: You can ask them when it comes up. Just a phone call away..

Answer (score 2):

The significance, if any, is going to be specific to the company.  Sometimes a "Foo Technician 1" is the entry-level role for a Foo Technician.  Sometimes it's the most experienced role.  Sometimes, an organization will document their naming/ numbering convention on their web site (this is somewhat common for roles in government and other public entities).  Most often, though, the job description is going to be a more useful representation of what the job entails than the title.

Comment: Sometimes even the "regular" names can be a bit uhh... interesting. In my company, an entry/junior level position is called Software Engineer, and the first promotion is to Software Engineer Lead :) Then comes Senior Software Engineer...

Comment: And sometimes these titles actually mean something (achieved a certain level of expertise) other times they really don't (negotiated well)

Comment: Usually they mean what pay band the job is in.  HOwever, only the company knows for sure what the pay differntial between a XYZ2 and an XYZ3 is. Often there are more stringent qualifications for the higher pay band as well. But if it is a level 1 and you are more qualified than that, it's an unhill battle to get paid for your qualifications when they don't actually need them for the job. Unless they also can make a case for the higher role based on their business (some jobs ar advertised at multiple levels).